# Check value even if it doesn't match validation

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, worksheet-function, google-sheets-arrayformula

In my Google spreadsheet, I have a column `G` of dates that interviews are/have been scheduled on. There is a validation set on it to validate for dates with a warning. Every once in a while, when someone was adding historical data but didn't know the right date they just put an `x` that the event has occurred (or `cancelled` if it was cancelled, or a variety of other non-blank statuses).

I'm now trying to use Query to get for all rows where that column is empty (regardless of validation)

I have

```
=QUERY('Interview Planning'!A:G, "select D, A, F, G WHERE G IS NULL")
```

But seem to be getting back any row for which G is not a valid date, not just where it is `NULL`.

How do I make it ignore the validation?

Demo of the issue:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14HmBvzjjo_z88WtfKAwYckIUNruTA8ivZEUaefKj2qw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Convert G column format to `plain text`

Comment: Then I lose the date validation and I no longer get a calendar picker...unless there's some way to do that in-query?

Comment: `=arrayformula(QUERY('Interview Planning'!A:G&"", "select Col4, Col1, Col6, Col7 WHERE Col7 IS NULL"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
=QUERY('Interview Planning'!A:G; "select D, A, F, G where G = ''"; 1)
```

and also select column G end set it as plain text

**[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TuV1W89rY505jhICtekgRdjWwgSNt_GHOt9z87-2Nw4/edit#gid=0)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the `; 0`? When I changed it to `G = ''` then it stopped showing *any* rows

Comment: @GeorgeMauer `; 0` means "header of query disabled". probably you need american notation... try this: `=QUERY('Interview Planning'!A:G, "select D, A, F, G where G = ''", 0)`

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in the docs after doing it. Still doesn't work....when I change it to this then *none* of the results come up

Comment: @GeorgeMauer well, its hard to help you if I am in the dark. can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Fair enough, here is a demo of the issue https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14HmBvzjjo_z88WtfKAwYckIUNruTA8ivZEUaefKj2qw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not clear how you got this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ijAIgoWrRBX-vT01Bloyxq9-YC0gj7TL3A7eFyKjSAY/edit?usp=sharing Mine shows up `#N/A` - You said "set it as plain text" - what does that mean? I still very much want the data validation on the column as *most* of the time it should contain a date and the datepicker is very helpful

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I can show you on picture... select column B and set it on Plain Text

Comment: Aha! Thank you. No clue at all why that works, but it does. `IS NULL` works in that case too